# Trying to run nodemon wih concurrently

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

Hey i'm trying to run nodemon to perform the command npm start which uses concurrently to open 3 nodejs processes

this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Classic website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {    
    "site": "node site/index.js",
    "socket": "node socket/index.js",
    "bots": "node bots/index.js",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run site\" \"npm run socket\" \"npm run bots\" "
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gsa",
    "web"
  ],
  "author": "sas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

However when i run nodemon i get an error -

> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\skindole\index.js'

Comment: Do you have the `index.js` file at this location => D:\skindole\ ?

Comment: I don't want/have index.js in the location

Answer (score 2):

What command exactly are you entering when you run nodemon? I think perhaps if you remove `"main": "index.js",` from the package.json you may have success.

I think what you want to do is in the start scripts for each of the site, socket, and bots replace `node` with `nodemon`.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with concurrently, however, adding --raw param to concurrently did a trick for me.

```json
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "wave": "concurrently --raw  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server \"" 
},
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using  && instead of concurrent?

```
"start": "npm run site && npm run socket && npm run bots"
```

Comment: same issue, I don't want/have index.js in the location